# How to make random mutations

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a project on natural selection for cells for fun. Each code has "dna" which is just a set of instructions. The dna can either have REMOVE WASTE, DIGEST FOOD, or REPAIR WALL. I won't really go into detail what they do, because that would take too long. But the only reason evolution really happens is through genetic mutations. I'm wondering if this is possible in javascript, and how to do it. For example, the starting cell has 5 dna strands. But if it reproduces, the child can have 4, or 6. And some of the dna strands can be altered. This is my code so far:

```
var strands = ["DIGEST FOOD", "REPAIR WALL", "REMOVE WASTE"];
var dna = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (parent) {
        // something about the parents dna, and the mutation chance
    }
    else {
        dna.push(strands[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]); // if cell doesn't have parent
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering if this is possible in javascript, and how to succesfully do it. Sorry if the question isn't too clear.
Edit: Let me rephrase a little. What I'm trying to achieve is a genetic mutation in the new cell. Like:

```
if (parent) {
dna.push(parent);
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
changeStrand(num);
}
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
addStrand(num);
}
if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
removeStrand(num);
}
}
function changeStrand() {
// change the strand
}
function newStrand(num) {
// add random strands
}
function removeStrand(num) {
// remove random strands
}
```

or something like that

Comment: You're right--it isn't too clear. You have too much information about biology and not enough about the mathematics you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

For a genetic algorithm, you basically want to take two slices from each parent and stitch them together, whilst ensuring the end result is still a valid dna strand.

For a fixed sized DNA sequence (such a N queens positions), the technique would be to pick a random slice point (1-3 | 4-8) and then combine these slices from the parents to create a child.

For your usecase, you need two random slices who sum of sizes adds upto 4-6. So possibly two slices of size 2-3. You could potentially take one from the front, and the other from the back. Else you could first pick a random output size, and then fill it will two random sequences for either parent.

Array.slice() and Array.splice() are probably the functions you want to use.

You can also add in a random mutation to the end result. Viruses at the speed limit of viable genetic evolution have an average of 1 mutation per transcription. Which means some transcriptions won’t have mutations, which is equivalent to allowing some of the parents in the parent generation to survive.

You can also experiment with different variations. Implement these as feature flags, and see what works best in practice.

Also compare with Beam Search, which essentially keeps a copy of the N best results from each generation. You may or may not want to keep the best from the parent generation to survive unmutated.

Another idea is to compute a distance metric between individuals, and add a cost for being too close to an existing member of the population, and this will select for genetic diversity.

> In the standard model, variation occurs both by point mutations in the letter sequence and by “crossover” (in which the DNA of an offspring is generated by combining long sections of DNA from each parent).
>
> The analogy to local search algorithms has already been described; the principal difference between stochastic beam search and evolution is the use of sexual reproduction, wherein successors are generated from multiple organisms rather than just one. The actual mechanisms of evolution are, however, far richer than most genetic algorithms allow. For example, mutations can involve reversals, duplications, and movement of large chunks of DNA; some viruses borrow DNA from one organism and insert it in another, and there are transposable genes that do nothing but copy themselves many thousands of times within the genome. There are even genes that poison cells from potential mates that do not carry the gene, thereby increasing their own chances of replication. Most important is the fact that the genes themselves encode the mechanisms whereby the genome is reproduced and translated into an organism. In genetic algorithms, those mechanisms are a separate program that is not represented within the strings being manipulated.

- Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach. (Third edition) by Stuart Russell and Peter Norvig.

Comment: This is a really good answer! Unfortunately, I'm going for asexual reproduction. But I will do sexual reproduction after asexual, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have random numbers you can use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) for that. In the linked page there are also some examples for getting values between x and y for example:

```
// Source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random 
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 
}
```

I am not sure this is what you try to achieve - since you already make use of the Math.random() function.